# In Python, trying to remove last comma in print statement output

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to come up with a way to remove the last comma in the output of this print statement. The trick is trying to get everything to come out on a single output line while removing the trailing comma.

My Code

```
def showChaos(n):
  for i in range(10):
    n = 3.9 * n * (1-n)
    print(n, end=",")
showChaos(0.99)
```

Output

> 0.03861000000000003,0.1447651448100001,0.4828519708667452,0.9738531858776956,0.09930631711087627,0.34883383272172636,0.8858802804945481,0.39427599558925047,0.9314074960762876,0.24916153208383285,

Comment: there are so many ways to go about this. You can remove the last char via slicing, check the loop index `i` to see if its the last iteration to change the print end variable, etc. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def showChaos(n):
  result_list = []
  for i in range(10):
    n = 3.9 * n * (1-n)
    result_List.append(str(n))
  print(",".join(result_list))
showChaos(0.99)
```

You can store intermediate results as strings in a list and just join them before printing.

Alternatively, calculate and print the last value after the loop:

```
def showChaos(n):
  for i in range(9):
    n = 3.9 * n * (1-n)
    print(n, end=",")
 n = 3.9 * n * (1-n)
 print(n)
showChaos(0.99)
```